# JS Form using DataFire, how to make it redirect or just send back success?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to use DataFire to setup a form and based the project on the following GitHub project:

https://github.com/DataFire-repos/contact-us-base

The HTML form works and I successfully receive emails. However, it just sends me to a blank page which is the action url I am posting too. Is there a way to use Datafile for forms, but not redirect to a page like this? I have read some things about using AJAX, but that doesn't seem like a feature on DataFire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX with DataFire. You just need to send a POST request to the contact URL, e.g. using jquery.post()

You can also create a custom HTTP response for the contact action using the documentation at the bottom of this page: https://docs.datafire.io/Introduction/Hello_World

Hope that helps!